# Need help to switch between to pictures in stickman game

Tags: java, jframe

I'm trying to make a simple stickman game where the stickman runs. I've added 2 pictures; 1 where he's standing and 1 where he's running. Have made a JFrame and have tried to switch between the pictures in it by adding the first pic then remove it and add the another.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Spil extends JFrame {
private static String path_for_image = "index.jpeg";
private static String path2_for_image = "run.jpeg";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("STICKMAN");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(path_for_image);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);

    ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(path2_for_image);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(image2);

    while(true){
        add(label);
        label.move(10, 0);
        if(label.isEnabled()){
            remove(label);
            add(label2);
        } else {
            remove(label2);
            add(label);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

^^Here I make the JFrame and the code below is my main class:

EDIT:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Spil extends JFrame {
private static String path_for_image = "index.jpeg";
private static String path2_for_image = "run.jpeg";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("STICKMAN");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(path_for_image);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);

    ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(path2_for_image);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(image2);

    while(true){
        frame.add(label);
        label.move(10, 0);
        if(label.isEnabled()){
            frame.remove(label);
            frame.add(label2);
        } else {
            frame.remove(label2);
            frame.add(label);
        }
    }
 }
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Spil run = new Spil();
    run.run();
 }
}
```

The problem is that the JFrame appears but without the pictures

Comment: Have you tried `repaint()`ing your JFrame?

Comment: change the image icon instead adding remove jlable.and what's the point of doing this inside a while true?

Comment: @FastSnail The label is added in the while statement.

Comment: So instead of jlabel label2 = new Jlabel(image2) I've to write frame label2 (image2); ?

Comment: @user4476151 From the look of this, you just need to add a `this.repaint()` at the end of your `while` loop. You're adding and removing components, but you're not repainting the graphics.

Comment: @SaviourSelf : No I haven't. What do I've to change?

Comment: @SaviourSelf: It didn't work

Comment: the most problem is `add(label);` you should use `frame.add(label);`
since you are not use extended class as frame remove extends keyword.also use `swing timer` .

Comment: OH WOW! I see it now! He has 2 JFrames! His class extends JFrame. When he calls add(label), he's adding it to the extension, and not to the frame he defined!

Comment: aslo `label.isEnabled()` always `true` so your second condition not run.and this is not a way of animating you need to add time gap .also you loop will block the edt thread .swing timer is the easy way

Comment: Can you please show me where I should do this?

Comment: You're blocking the event dispatch thread, preventing the Ui from been updated or allowing it to process any other events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use swing timer

there are bunch of problems in your code

1) `add(label);` should be `frame.add(label);` you have extends your class with frame .but you have created frame local varible and used it.so add will add to your class/jframe instead of frame.so your frame don't have a lable.
either you can remove extends keyword or you can use your `Spil` class as a jframe then you don't need to create a another frame variable.
<strike>`JFrame frame = new JFrame("STICKMAN");`</strike>)  .see example 2 how to do using `extends jframe`

2) `label.isEnabled()` always true so you never execute else block.to `isEnable` be false it should be disabled.

3) removing and adding `jlables` is really inefficient you can easily change image icon.

4) infinite loop will block the [Edt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and freez your gui.swing timer will handle this without blocking EDT

5) animation need a time gap if you do very fast it really doesn't look nice.in this example i have set time gap to 10 `millisecond`. you can change speed of your animation by changing value 10.

swing timer is easy to use and perfect for your requirement.

**example 1** without extends JFrame

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Spil {

    private static final ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("index.jpeg");
    private static final ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("run.jpeg");

    boolean bool = false;

    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("STICKMAN");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(img1);

        frame.add(label);
        Timer t = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (bool) {
                    label.setIcon(img1);
                } else {
                    label.setIcon(img2);
                }
                bool=!bool;
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spil run = new Spil();
        run.run();
    }
}
```

**example 2** / extends Jframe

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Spil extends JFrame {

    private static final ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("index.jpeg");
    private static final ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("run.jpeg");

    boolean bool = false;

    public void run() {
        super.setTitle("STICKMAN");

        JLabel label = new JLabel(img1);
        add(label);

        Timer t = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (bool) {
                    label.setIcon(img1);
                } else {
                    label.setIcon(img2);
                }
                bool = !bool;
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spil run = new Spil();
        run.setSize(400,300);
        run.setVisible(true);
        run.run();
    }
}
```